# ×REACT: How can I solve: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Alright you guys, I am simply trying to create a "user" specified as toy in this example. This code had been running fine yesterday allowing me to create "users" with just a username and email.
Here is my code:

```
    async postData(path, data) {
    const url = `http://localhost:3001${path}`
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'CORS',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    })
console.log(response)
return response
}

clickHandler = async () => {
    await this.postData("/toys", this.state)
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state)
}
```

My GET is working & showing my previously created users in my console but mapping the information returns this error:

[image: Error]

Please help!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests you need to use correct request mode (which is `mode: 'cors'` - lowercase).

```
async postData(path, data) {
    const url = `http://localhost:3001${path}`
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // uppercase
        mode: 'cors', // lowercase
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    })
    console.log(response)
    return response
}
```

Also it is generally adviced to add error handling

```
clickHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await this.postData("/toys", this.state)

      if (!resp.ok) { ...}

    } catch (e) {
      // do smth if error
      console.error(`Unable to create a toy due to ${e}`)
    }
}
```